# Archimedean Property Corollary proof

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove one of the Archmedian properties corollaries.

---

The corollary states:

*If $x$ is a real number such that $x>0$ then there exists a natural number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n−1\le x <n$.*

---

From the Archmedian property, I know that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $n>x$ and from the Well Ordering Principle I know that for any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ there is a least element, however, how do I show that $n-1\le x$?

Comment: You got the archimedian property wrong, for every x in R you can find n, s.t $x<n$.

Comment: @Riquelme but that is what I said.

Comment: No, you said there exists x in R s. t x <n

Comment: This is from my book, "If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then there is a positive integer n
such that $n > x$." Not sure what the difference is?

Comment: This is true, what you said in your next paragraph is what I was referring to

Comment: @Riquelme but aren't both the same thing?

Comment: No, they are not! Try rephrasing your statement with quantors!

Answer (score -2):

look at all those natural numbers $n$ which is larger than $x$, and choose the smallest one (e.g. $n_0$) by well-ordering principle, then argue that $n_0-1$ is also a natural number(shall make use of the fact that $x>0$). Hence it must follow that $n_0-1\le x$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?